# Simple but confusing question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, substitution

Suppose we have a function
$$
f(x)= x+1
$$
for $0<x<1$. Introduce $y=x^3$ for $0<y<1$. So in $y$ space we would write
$$
f(y)= \sqrt[3]{y}+1.
$$
But why is that? Why isn't it just
$$
f(y) = y+1?
$$
What I am asking is, in the first equation we have a formula for what happens when you pass an argument to the function, why can't we apply that to $y$? I would think that the underlying reason is that in the first case we are mapping from $X$ space and from the second we are mapping from $Y$ space, but here even the domains are the same.

For some reason this is very confusing to me. I have always found this award even when doing differential equations by substitution.

Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: $
f(x)= \sqrt[3]{y}+1.
$ and $
f(y)= y+1.
$

Comment: Hi @geetha290krm. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: $f(x) = x + 1 = \sqrt[3]{y} + 1.$  Alternatively, for any value of $x$, $f(x) = x + 1$.  Here, $x$ is just a place holder.  This explains why $f(y) = y + 1.$  Your confusion is in expressing $f(x)$ in terms of $(y)$ versus expressing $f(y)$ in terms of $(y)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I think that this somewhat clarifies it. However, I am struggling to see how this applies to when we are say solving DEs by substitution. We had a DE for a function $f$ in terms of $y$. We want to find $f(y)$. Then suppose we made the substituion as in the above and get a solution $f(x)=x+1$. Then I know it will be wrong to just plug in $y$ for $x$ in each space, I will have to use the inversion of the transformation. This however, will give $f(x)=$ some expression in $y$. But I want to find $f(y)$. Could you clarify what is going on here?

Answer (score -2):

the formula reads:

$(\forall x)(\forall y)[x,y\in(0,1)\land (f(x)=(x+1))\land y=x^3)]$

So $x,y$ are bound variables.

I.e. $x,y$ are in the scope of the quantifiers $(\forall x), (\forall y)$, they appear in the first formula following the quantifiers.

This is why you make the first substitution.